# How to build ISPAC using VSTS

Tags: ssis, azure-pipelines

It appears that building ISPAC using MSBuild is near impossible. I'm hoping I can find a way to create ISPACs in the VSTS build processes, but it doesnt appear to be straight forward.

there is a VSTS task by ToxicGlobe
https://github.com/ToxicGlobe/VSTS-SSIS-Extension
However support seems minimum, and there isnt alot of traction.

how does the real world create ISPACs in a common CI process?

Comment: We use PowerShell for this, although we do it locally. But I guess it could be used in VSTS also. I just found the following link, I think you might find this useful: http://abelsquidhead.com/index.php/2016/10/06/build-and-deploy-ssis-packages-using-vsts/

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t such build-in task available in VSTS, but you can refer to the source code of VSTS-SSIS-Extension to custom the build/release task to meet your requirement through VSTS extension: [Add a build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task)

Answer (score 0):

I use this command:

```
devenv SolutionName.sln /Rebuild
```

In the Bin folder of the project, you are going to find the .ispac file, Remember to include the path of devenv.exe in the System Variable "Path"